# Automatically open browser upon logon

Tags: windows-vista, firefox, browser, login

I have Vista on my laptop and can't find the internet setting that used to exist which easily gave u the option of automatically opening ur browser, which in my case is Foxfire, when logging on. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

The quickest way is to click Start, go to All Programs, then find a group/folder called "Startup". Right click and choose New > Shortcut, then type "www.google.com" or whichever site you want in the box. This should then open your default browser on the page you set.

[image]

[image]

1. Right click on Startup
2. Click Open
3. Right click on any empty space
4. Click / Hover on "New"
5. Click Shortcut

Answer (score 1):

[image]

To view this again you must open it in a new tab or page.

Comment: Glary tools are the best :)